# 「雨が降っているぜ」の「ぜ」の意味について

Tags: particles, register, nuances

さっき、お弁当を買ってきた三十代の男性同僚が、入室したら「外雨が降っているぜ！早く弁当買っといた方がいいかも！」と勢い良く言った。

その「ぜ」の意味はなんだべ？

「行くぜ」ならなんとなく分かるんだが、今の文脈だとさっぱり迷ってしまうんだ…

Answer (score 2):

「[語尾の「～ぜ」というのはどこの方言でどんな意味ですか（駄）](http://komachi.yomiuri.co.jp/t/2009/0805/255509.htm)」によると、
“降っているぞ”→“降っているぞよ”→“降っているぜ”
と変化した言葉とのことです。

しかし現代で「～ぜ」の意味するところは、
[役割語](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BD%B9%E5%89%B2%E8%AA%9E)としての方が大きいように思えます。

Comment: In the question, ぜ is not 役割語 because it was actually used in the real world, unless the speaker tried to act as someone else.  So I am not sure how relevant this answer is to the question.

Comment: Sorry, that's right. Is ぜ 男性語 in this case?

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto Does "役割語" mean something along the lines of "typical sentence ending pattern supposedly frequently used by a certain demographic and stereotyped as such so that when it's used in media it's supposed to make you think that the person speaking as such is belonging to that demographic"? I ask because I'm not too good at reading Japanese yet and not entirely sure what it means. So it'd be good if someone could countercheck my understanding.

Comment: @Flaw: 役割語 is a stereotypical way of speech of some group of people, and by “stereotypical” I mean that it is irrelevant whether those group of people actually use it.  For example, if someone says わしは本を読んでおるんじゃ in a novel, the reader understands that the speaker is an old person.  Many 役割語 are sentence-ending words (such as じゃ), but some are not (such as わし and ～しておる).  Although 役割語 is an important technique in Japanese literature, it is not very relevant here because ぜ in the question is actually used in the real world.

Comment: I would count ぜ as 男性語 (a word which is primarily used by male speakers), although it is also used by female speakers.  However, understanding that ぜ is a 男性語 does not explain much about the meaning of ぜ.

Answer (score 1):

単に男らしさ、荒荒しさを表現しようとしているのと違いますのんか。その同僚の方は体育会系でっしゃろ。なぜ「行く」の場合は分かって「雨が降る」の場合はお分かりにならないのか分かりませんねん。意志の有無を問題にしてらっしゃるのですやろか。そげなことは気にせんでよかと思いますばい。

Comment: いや、体育会系では全くない方なんだけど…
男らしさを表現する助詞だって知っていた。それとも「さあ、行くぜ！」は「さあ、行こう！」に近いってニュアンスがあるんじゃないかと思ってるので、確実なことを言うと変に思うんだ。